# Why do the route tables behave differently in Windows 8.1 and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, routing, lan

I have the following network layout:
`192.168.3.0/24` - WiFi, **Internet**;
`192.168.46.0/24` - LAN, used for local homegroup, Synergy kbd/mouse sharing only. **No Internet.**

Windows 8.1, `192.168.3.126`, `192.168.46.130`
Windows 7,   `192.168.3.125`, `192.168.46.137`

`route print` at Windows 8.1: *(irrelevant records skipped)*

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.3.1    192.168.3.126     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.46.1   192.168.46.130     20
      192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.3.126    281
    192.168.3.126  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.3.126    281
    192.168.3.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.3.126    281
     192.168.46.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.46.130    276
   192.168.46.130  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.46.130    276
   192.168.46.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.46.130    276
```

`route print` at Windows 7: *(irrelevant records skipped)*

```
IPv4 Route Table                                                            
=========================================================================== 
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric 
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.46.1   192.168.46.137     30 
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.3.1    192.168.3.125     25 
      192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.3.125    281 
    192.168.3.125  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.3.125    281 
    192.168.3.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.3.125    281 
     192.168.46.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.46.137    286 
   192.168.46.137  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.46.137    286 
   192.168.46.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.46.137    286
```

Initially I had a problem when Windows 7 default routing was directed towards `192.168.46.1`, hence it did not see the Internet once the LAN is connected.

This happened because the interfaces had wrong metrics (`20` and `25`, correspondingly).
I changed the interface metric as shown above (`30` for LAN) as suggested in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/237892/why-is-my-laptop-favoring-the-wireless-connection-over-my-lan-connection), so it started working fine.

My question is:

- Why Windows 8.1 needs no setting of metrics?
- Can it be because of different order of default route records in route table? (see first two records)
- If so, how can I *re-order the default gateway records* in the route table?

Comment: why does the lan interface need a default gateway if you're not using it for to go out to the Internet?

Comment: @Zalmy probably, it doesn't need. This is the default setting and I would better keep it. Otherwise, when I connect the laptop to the LAN at another place, I would need to change it back. Is it correct?

Comment: I believe this has to do with the order in which the NICs were bound. I'd check to see if the priority of the NICs is swapped. http://techrena.net/view-change-network-adapter-card-priority-binding-order-windows-7/

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks, I checked this also (it's mentioned in the accepted answer for the linked question). The order of network adapters does not change neither the order of default gateways not the metrics. Even after reboot.

Comment: have you confirmed by MAC address that the same NIC is .3. on both OSs?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, `192.168.3.0/24` is the wireless network have control of; `.125` and `.126` are manually set to my laptops via the Wireless Access Point's DHCP settings.