# Route Internet to WiFi, 10.* to LAN Adapter

Tags: windows-7, routing

I have an active LAN (Ethernet) and WiFi connection.

When both are active it seems all traffic is routed to LAN but I want all internet traffic routed to WiFi and only internal IPs (10 . * . * . * ) routed to the LAN adapter.

How can I use `route add` make my WiFi Gateway the default for everything and my LAN Gateway only route 10.*?

Comment: Putting here as I'm not 100% sure. If you set a default gateway on your Wireless card to your router, but leave off a default gateway on your ether nic then windows should choose the wifi for all external traffic, this may need you to set a static ip on your LAN

Comment: Check out http://superuser.com/questions/455965/how-to-give-preference-over-one-network-connection-over-another and http://superuser.com/questions/436256/can-i-choose-wifi-over-ethernet-lan (Doesn't address per-adapter routing, though)

Answer (score 0):

It means you have probably set a gateway for both interfaces.

If you use the Ethernet interface only for network 10.x.x.x and nothing else (no network behind it), then simply remove the gateway from this interface. You don't need to add a route unless there is more networks behind the 10.x.x.x interface.